# Genre d’un adjectif dans une affirmation entre général et particulier, utilisant la 2e personne du singulier

Tags: grammaire, genre, oral

Dans le contexte de l’**oralité**, lorsque quelques hommes discutent entre eux de généralités rapportées à quelques personnes, il est possible qu’ils utilisent un pronom singulier pour introduire la généralité, et en particulier la deuxième personne. Par exemple :

> Quand tu cherches le trouble, tu as des chances de le trouver.

L’affirmation peut être exprimée d’une manière si générale que l’on puisse sans problème penser que celui qui l’émet s’inclut dans ce ***tu***, qui plus généralement exclut la personne qui parle.

Si la généralité en question introduit un adjectif qui ne soit pas épicène, le masculin, à n’en pas douter, sera utilisé :

> Tu te sens vraiment **idiot** quand ça t’arrive !

Si maintenant c’est un groupe de femmes, le féminin risque fort d’être utilisé :

> Tu te sens vraiment **idiote** quand ça t’arrive !

Dans le cas de groupe mixtes, où disons le nombre de femmes domine, ou qu’alors la conversation est surtout le fait de femmes même s’il y a des hommes à l’intérieur du groupe qui pourraient écouter et même intervenir à tout instant sans causer de scandale, on pourra tout de même imaginer que le féminin puisse être privilégié :

> — Tu te sens vraiment **idiote** quand ça t’arrive !
>   — Oh que si ! lance un tiers. Pas plus tard que ce matin, je posais une question sur internet, et v’là tout le monde qui me reprend sur l’exemple, qui n’était là que pour illustrer un peu. Je me suis vraiment senti **idiot** !

Il n’y a pas là de quoi s’insurger. L’homme s’est parfaitement senti concerné par le propos, et n’y a pas vu à mal que l’on ait mentionné le féminin pour une généralité, pas davantage qu’il ne s’est senti atteint dans sa virilité de correspondre à cette généralité exprimée au féminin.

Dans le cas d’une personne s’adressant à un petit groupe de gens tous de l’autre sexe, je dois avouer ne pas être entièrement certain de l’accord en genre de l’adjectif qui détonnerait le moins à l’oreille d’un(e) francophone, surtout en considérant la possible inclusion de l’orateur (ou oratrice) dans le ***tu***.

Peut-être le contexte générerait-il aussi des variations ?

- Un contexte où la généralité a une volonté plus descriptive, comme lors d’une conversation entre adultes.
- Un contexte plus pédagogique ou éducatif, par exemple une mère à ses jeunes fils ou un père à ses jeunes filles.

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse utiliser le féminin quand il y a plus de femmes que d'hommes, en tout cas je n'ai jamais vu ça. À la limite si les femmes sont en immense majorité (donc pas applicable à un groupe de 3-4 personnes), mais même comme ça c'est discutable.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat On ne trouvera certes pas de recommendations en ce sens dans les livres de grammaire, mais j'ai souvent observé le féminin dans des groupes où je me trouvais. On pourra plus particulièrement penser à une femme parlant principalement à une autre, et accessoirement à tous ceux du groupe, hommes ou femmes, qui veulent l'écouter.

Comment: Je suis d'accord, mais dans ce cas-là, pas besoin de demander une règle, si ? Vu qu'on n'est plus sur des règles strictes, c'est toi qui vois on peut pas t'aider plus que ça. Si ça te paraît naturel, accorde comme tu le sens, si t'es pas trop sûre, restes sur les règles des livres de grammaires ^^ En tout cas c'est comme ça que je fais.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Je ne demande pas une règle, simplement la manière qui détonnerait le moins à des oreilles francophones.

Comment: **Boire trop d'eau vous alourdit.**

Comment: Ce mot, « adresse », semble être un anglicisme ; je ne le trouve pas dans le Larousse et de plus, en anglais on ne trouve que « a discourse delivered to an audience » en tant qu'acception qui approche ce qui est nommé ici, c'est à dire « une caractérisation » ; comment le justifiez-vous, si ce n'est pas trop vous demander ?

Comment: [Déclaration formulée à l'intention d'un destinataire](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/adresse)

Comment: « Qui éprouve une sensation de lourdeur, de poids, incitant à l'immobilité, au repos : _Se sentir [lourd](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/lourd/47913?q=lourd#47833) après un repas_ [...] » (Larousse en ligne). Bien moi je comprends parfaitement, je trouve ça commun, je vois pas pourquoi on aurait préféré comprendre un sens familier. Peut-être mettre entre parenthèses _heavy_ pour être mieux compris la prochaine fois ?! Des réponses préfèrent t'aider à t'exprimer dans ta propre langue plutôt que de répondre, laisse-moi les aider à comprendre la sens que prend la lourdeur...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Que voulez-vous? Nous parlons, semble-t-il, un sous-français inélégant et avons besoin d’un petit coup de pied civilisateur bien placé de temps en temps. Merci de votre soutien, y compris celui passé à la poële.

Comment: Peut-être que finalement le québécois est une langue différente et qu'il est inutile d'essayer de le mettre en valeur au sein d'une majorité linguistique. On est moins tolérant avec lui qu'avec le français approximatif d'un apprenant, qu'avec l'anglicisme, c'est fatiguant. Si le réseau autorisait la création de nouveaux sites pour les langues et que j'avais du temps à y consacrer j'entreprendrais de soutenir un site pour le québécois. On est un peuple. Je sais pas combien de fois on doit accepter de se faire dire _speak white_ par d'autres peuples qui nous ont soit inféodés ou abandonnés...

Answer (score 1):

*Lourd* ou *idiot* n'étant pas des adverbes mais des adjectifs, ils doivent s'accorder en genre et en nombre avec la ou les personnes représentées par le pronom sujet.

On dira donc à une femme que l'on tutoie :

> Tu te sens tellement idiote.

À une femme que l'on vouvoie :

> Vous vous sentez tellement idiote.

À un homme que l'on vouvoie :

> Vous vous sentez tellement idiot.

À plusieurs hommes (et/ou garçons) :

> Vous vous sentez tellement idiots.

À plusieurs femmes (et/ou jeunes filles) :

> Vous vous sentez tellement idiotes.

À un groupe composé de femmes et d'hommes (même s'il n'y en a qu'un) :

> Vous vous sentez tellement idiots.

Idem s'il s'agit d'un group mixte comportant des enfants.

Quand il s'agit de généralité, le pronom *on* peut être utilisé :

> On se sent tellement idiot.

mais *on* pouvant aussi remplacer la plupart des autres pronoms, on pourra aussi trouver :

> On se sent tellement idiote/idiots/idiotes.

suivant qui se cache derrière ce *on*. Si le *on* englobe des personnes de sexe masculin, le féminin ne sera pas utilisé.

Il arrive aussi que la deuxième personne soit générique. Dans ce cas le ou les interlocuteurs sont invités à s'imaginer, se mettre à la place de ces *tu* ou *vous*.

Le singulier peut alors être utilisé même si plusieurs personnes écoutent, voire même doit être utilisé si le pluriel est illogique :

> A Monaco, si tu pars en tête, tu gagnes !

On peut aussi trouver un singulier en reprise d'un pluriel :

> Plus folles que ça, tu meurs.

Si l'accord est au féminin alors que l'on s'adresse à un groupe mixte, on exclut de fait les hommes éventuellement présents, mais rien n'interdit à ces derniers de s'inclure *a posteriori*.

Answer (score 0):

Pour commencer, il est peu commun d'utiliser une phrase tel que:

> Trop boire d’eau te rend lourd.

L'adjectif "**Lourd**" dans cette phrase étant plus enclin à signifier "pénible, agaçant"

> Trop boire d’eau te rend agacant.

Perd donc de son sens.

Lourd étant dans ce contexte souvent un adjectif dont la signification est la suivante:

1. difficile à supporter ou à réaliser
2. qui manque de finesse intellectuelle

   Source: [Reverso expression](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-synonymes/T%27es+lourd+%C3%A0+la)

---

Toute fois pour vous répondre à propos de ces cas particuliers :

- Un homme s’adresse à deux femmes seulement.

> Trop boire d’eau **vous** rend lourd**es**.

- Une femme s’adresse à deux hommes seulement.

> Trop boire d’eau **vous** rend lourd**s**.

- Un père s’adresse à ses deux jeunes filles.

> Trop boire d’eau **vous** rend lourd**es**.

- Une mère s’adresse à ses deux jeunes fils.

> Trop boire d’eau **vous** rend lourd**s**.

Comment: 1) La phrase proposée n'était qu'un exemple parmi de nombreux autres possibles, mais elle est surtout celle que j'ai utilisée hier, et je me trouvais dans l'un des quatre cas que j'ai proposés. En parlant d'eau et de lourdeur, on n'a pas cru alors que je mentionnais que l'eau rendait peu subtil. En fait de liquide, l'alcool est plus souvent à blâmer pour ce genre d'effets. 2) J'ai pour cela utilisé **le singulier**, et un accord quelconque qui m'a semblé bizarre, quoique tous les autres me semblent aussi étranges aujourd'hui. Alors je pose la question...

Answer (score 0):

Dans le cas de certaines énonciations il est préférable de ne pas chercher à un genre qui convient et de choisir du langage qui ne dépend pas du genre.

> Trop boire d'eau te rend lourd.

Étant donné que des expressions telles que « je suis lourd », « nous nous sentons lourd », « ça me rend lourd », etc. ne sont pas très esthétiques ni très judicieuses,  et que l'on parle essentiellement  de « lourdeur d'estomac » et de « nourritures lourdes (à digérer) », de plus que ce problème de genre complique inutilement les choses, il me semble que l'utilisateur avisé du langage évitera tout cela en bloc et dira quelque chose comme « *Trop boire d'eau donne des lourdeurs d'estomac.* » ou bien « *Une trop grande ingestion d'eau est lourde à l'estomac.* ».

Lorsqu'il n'existe pas un palliatif qui améliore la qualité de l'expression, il existe une difficulté réelle.

Il faut dire que les emplois des secondes personnes  du singulier et du  pluriel dans un sens général sont souvent des emplois au bord de l'équivoque et ils devraient être évités autant que possible. Leur substituer l'emploi de « on » est souvent préférable mais malheureusement ne résout pas le problème de nos jours comme il existe une nouvelle et forte insistance a accorder les adjectifs selon le sexe de la personne qui parle et non pas selon la nature du pronom « on ».

Les trois premiers cas sont sans problème ; dans le quatrième il n'y a pas de solutions sauf celle d'utiliser « on » en respectant l'accord traditionnel ;

— On se sens vraiment idiot quand ça arrive !
– Oh que si ! lance un tiers. Pas plus tard que ce matin, je posais une question sur internet, et v’là tout le monde qui me reprend sur l’exemple, qui n’était là que pour illustrer un peu. Je me suis vraiment senti idiot !

Si le locuteur du sexe féminin utilise le féminin pour « idiot » elle élimine du dialogue toute partie des interlocuteurs qui sont du sexe masculin, lesquels peuvent avoir tendance à penser que ce qui est exprimé ne s'adresse pas à eux ou n'appartient pas à un contexte masculin ; si elle utilise le masculin l'inverse se produit, de plus que s'ajoute à cela le contexte plutôt inhabituel d'exclusion de la personne qui parle, ce qui rend le message plus douteux. Il est certain que l'on s'accommode de ces situations de légère indétermination, que l'on ajuste prestement en pensée la portée des assertions pour rétablir la notion qui importe, mais la formulation même d'une question à ce sujet par l'OP montre que cela ne facilite pas l'expression.

Le cinquième cas ne se prête pas plus à un langage précis en terme de ces généralisations par un pronom de la seconde personne.

Prenant le cas suivant du maitre de sexe féminin qui s'adresse à des élèves de sexe masculin, il n'existe pas, il me semble une plus grande propension à utiliser le féminin (… vous sentir idiote.) tant que le contexte reste dans la plus grande généralité ; évidemment, si l'assertion formulée traite d'un problème féminin (comme par exemple une remarque inconsidérée en ce qui concerne la menstruation à une jeune fille qui a eu ses premières règles) il n'est plus de mise de chercher quel genre est le plus approprié, quelle que soit la composition de l'audience, quel que soit le sexe du locuteur ; mais on s'en tient à la plus grande généralité et dans ce cas-là rien ne justifie que l'un ou l'autre des deux genres soit pris comme référence. On doit, il me semble, devoir réaliser qu'il y a un défaut inhérent à la structure du langage, qu'il y manque un genre, le genre mixte, et que l'on ne fera pas de bon travail en matière d'établir des préceptes solides et sains tant que l'on essaiera de faire fonctionner la langue dans ce domaine au moyen de recettes de rebouteux.

Comment: Suranalyse ici aussi. On se concentre sur la forme quand je suis curieux du fond. Si l'on aime pas parler de la lourdeur (au sens de pesant, pas au sens d'avoir des crampes, rien à voir avec l'estomac), que l'on fournisse au moins un autre exemple qui nous semblera plus valide. La question est étiquettée «oral» et le sujet est clair et n'a rien à voir avec la lourdeur ou l'eau, mais avec des hommes et des femmes discutant de généralités rapportées à quelques personnes (soi-même ou leurs quelques interlocuteurs). S'il vous plaît un petit effort pour ne pas regarder le doigt qui pointe la lune.

Comment: @Montéedelait Il faudrait choisir un exemple incontournable alors ; cependant la façon de traiter le problème que je présente n'est pas moins une option qui le résout  dans de nombreux cas, et cela de façon très pratique ; il ne s'agit pas vraiment de suranalyse mais d'analyse partielle.

Comment: Il conviendrait d'ajouter une référence à une citation comme *«Étant donné que des expressions telles que “je suis lourd”, “nous nous sentons lourd”, “ça me rend lourd”, etc. ne sont pas très esthétiques ni très judicieuses»*, car en affirmant une telle chose, aussi ciblée, il y a le risque de se prononcer contre les habitudes langagières habituelles d'une poignée de millions de francophones. Les opinions personnelles n'ayant que peu de poids, et pouvant biaiser une argumentation, les soutenir avec des données me semble plus judicieux sur ce site.

Comment: Par ailleurs, une addition assez bien faite ce matin. Certaines tournures sont un peu lourdes, et certaines considérations sont encore frappées du sceau de l'opinion personnelle, mais il y a clairement un fond bien réfléchi, et pour ce je salue l'ajout. Je comprends aussi qu'il soit peut-être inutile de chercher à établir des règles, mais à défaut de celles-ci, peut-être un guide un peu mieux découpé, avec le pertinent exemple des débuts de menstruations et possiblement un autre qui soit davantage lié aux hommes ou garçons?

Comment: @Montéedelait La remarque sur l'esthétique et le judicieux reflètent un état de chose qui est assez évident et qui demande un aperçu général des définitions de dictionnaire (cela corrobore d'ailleurs  le début dans cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34893/17649) : on ne trouve pas un report de la qualité de lourdeur sur l'être tout entier à partir de l'existence de cette qualité dans un des aspect de l'être ou de ses parties ; il est toujours question de la lourdeur de la chose elle-même ; on ne trouve pas ces extensions de sens en définition ; (champ 1)

Comment: @Montéedelait cela tend à montrer que ces possibilité ont été trouvées peu judicieuses jusqu'à présent ; l'esthétique ne réfère qu'à une certaine pureté du langage qui fait défaut : on sera lourd lorsque l'on a trop mangé, lourd lorsque on a les jambes lourdes, lourd lorsque notre style linguistique est lourd, lourd lorsque le temps est lourd, etc. J'aurai bien voulu un exemple de plus mais le présent m'a couté beaucoup de temps pour m'arranger à ne pas faire les choses à moitié.  (fin)